# What's the difference between 1- Trace Topology, 2- Subspace Topology, 3- Relative Topology, and 4- Induced Topology?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I need help with some topology terms... So what is the difference between:

1- Trace Topology

2- Subspace Topology

3- Relative Topology

4- Induced Topology

Or are they all the same thing?

Comment: They are all the same.

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 are for sure the same, but when you talk about the 'induced' topology (the topology induced by a function $f$), then you have the topology on $X$ that is induced by a function $f: X\to Y$. This topology is build to make $f$ continuous. The subspace topology is the from the inclusion induced topology, but I doubt you would refer to the subspace topology as 'induced topology' on its own. For example the product topology is the from the projections induced topology.

Comment: Now I get it!! Thank you both.